# Hadoop initial setup on AWS EC2?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, installation

I am just a newbie of Hadoop.

does anyone know how to setup hadoop on EC2(micro) instance?

or

It would be helpful if anyone knows good reference on-line links for Hadoop on EC2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have one reference link for installing Cloundera manager on EC2.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-create-a-cdh-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-via-cloudera-manager/